# Object isn't rotating properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, tools

I cannot rotate the wheel shown here properly or the wheel of the car will go above the car while rotating. I can't get the wheel to spin like it should for my project.[image]

[image: What could be the issue?]

What could be the issue?

Comment: Your object‘s origin point is not in the middle of the Wheel. Select your object and go to object - set origin to geometry. Then try again rotating.

Comment: Hello, if Chris' answer doesnt' work, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks! Finally got the wheels spinning! Thanks Chris!

Comment: you are welcome!